How to display DAX query result in single row
I have the below DAX query :
EVALUATE
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            FILTER (
                CROSSJOIN ( ALL ( Company[Country] ), ALL ( 'Date'[year] ) ),
                'Company'[Country] IN { "US", "CA" } && 'Date'[year] = "FY2022"
            ),
            "Sum", CALCULATE ( 'Total'[sum] ),
        ),
        "SUM", [Sum]
    )

i am getting the below two rows of output.
SUM
1234
5678

my objective is to return a single row with the total sum of "US" and "CA".
Does anyone know,how can i do it in a simple with the above code?
Thanks in advance

Can you give sample data?

If you need the code to be somewhat similar to what you posted, I think that it might be difficult because when you filter the Company table, you will always get 2 rows.

maybe you can try to create a measure.
    VAR tbl=
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                FILTER (
                    CROSSJOIN ( ALL ( Company[Country] ), ALL ( 'Date'[year] ) ),
                    'Company'[Country] IN { "US", "CA" } && 'Date'[year] = "FY2022"
                ),
                "Sum", CALCULATE ( 'Total'[sum] ),
            ),
            "SUM", [Sum]
        )
return sum([Sum])

or make the previous table as a temp to use that to create another one.
VAR tbl=
SELECTCOLUMNS (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            FILTER (
                CROSSJOIN ( ALL ( Company[Country] ), ALL ( 'Date'[year] ) ),
                'Company'[Country] IN { "US", "CA" } && 'Date'[year] = "FY2022"
            ),
            "Sum", CALCULATE ( 'Total'[sum] ),
        ),
        "SUM", [Sum]
    )

return summarize(tbl,"sum",sum([Sum]))

